# CalledProcessError when trying a crontab command

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I have a simple script that uses subprocess.check_output to run a crontab command. However, when I execute the script for crontab, it returns with an exit code of 1, and if I print the error output, it prints "no crontab for user", which is what it should print without going into error mode.

Here is my script:

```
import subprocess

    try:

        string = subprocess.check_output(['crontab','-l'])
        print "Yes! "
        print string
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print e.output
```

The weird thing is, if I run ls -l instead of crontab -l, everything runs as expected, and I get the output I want back. However, once I run crontab -l, here is what I get if I remove print e.output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python1.py", line 3, in <module>
    string = subprocess.check_output(['crontab','-l'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['crontab', '-l']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

As I mentioned above, e.output produces "no crontab for user", but that should not return as an error, it should return as normal output. Am I missing something here?